# Date picker and select2 not initialize in w2ui grid on invisible column

Tags: grid, w2ui

I have dynamic columns in w2grid column, In such column we have add date picker and select2. Date picker and select2  initialize in visible column but not initialize when horizontal scrolling. And when i horizontal scrolling to last column my all initialize datepicker and selct2 not working and they are not working. 
Please help me.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBye7.png

Comment: I have found issue, it's due to scrolling. When grid records scroll then grid refresh. So how can i reinitialize select2 and date picker on frid refresh?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Check every second either it is initialize or not.

```html
<script>
  setInterval(function(){
     if($('class_name').hasClass("select2-hidden-accessible")) {
     } else {
            $("class_name").select2();
     }
  }, 2000);
</script>
```